# TypeScript Conditional Types and typeof

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

So I've got this code that checks that builds up the `AnyOfTheAbove` `type` from a number of `string` constants:

```
const IT_COULD_BE_THIS = 'something';
const OR_THAT = 'something else';
const OR_EVEN = 'the other thing';

export type AnyOfTheAbove =
    | typeof IT_COULD_BE_THIS 
    | typeof OR_THAT 
    | typeof OR_EVEN;
```

I'd quite like to be able to write

```
export type AnyOfTheAbove = GetTypeof<
    | IT_COULD_BE_THIS 
    | OR_THAT 
    | OR_EVEN
>;
```

Or similar.  I have a feeling I can accomplish this with Conditional Types.  But all my attempts thus far have burned in flames.  Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **not possible** as a type won't accept a runtime object not preceded by `typeof`. (except for classes and enums)

If it's really about not writing `typeof` for *each object*, you can wrap **all objects** in a **function call**, then **extract types *once*** using `typeof`:

### Using Fake Function

```
// No value produced at runtime, but infers union type statically
function unionType<T>(...arr: T[]): T { return null as unknown as T }

const IT_COULD_BE_THIS = 'something'
const OR_THAT = 'something else'
const OR_EVEN = 'the other thing'

// Extract types from function call
type AnyOfTheAbove = typeof AnyOfTheAbove
const AnyOfTheAbove = unionType(
  IT_COULD_BE_THIS,
  OR_THAT,
  OR_EVEN
)
```

Which implies a runtime call (which will just return `null`), but permits to workaround the limitation.

### Using Tuple

```
// You need to specify `string` to infer each string correctly:
// https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26158
function tuple<T extends string[]>(...t: T) { return t }

const IT_COULD_BE_THIS = 'something'
const OR_THAT = 'something else'
const OR_EVEN = 'the other thing'

// Extract types from function call
type AnyOfTheAbove = typeof AllOfTheAbove[number]
const AllOfTheAbove = tuple(
    IT_COULD_BE_THIS,
    OR_THAT,
    OR_EVEN
)
```

---

In fact, both these solutions use Tuple, but one implies a fake runtime call, as the other will just wrap your array in a function call to correctly infer the types.

None really saves characters nor simplifies readability.

---

## Edit 26/08/2019

### Using Enum

If you can define all these strings in an enum, you can do:

```
enum AllEnum {
  IT_COULD_BE_THIS,
  OR_THAT,
  OR_EVEN,
}

// Static type
type All = keyof typeof AllEnum

// Access all strings at runtime
const allAtRuntime = Object.keys(AllEnum)
```

Comment: "You also have solutions using a Tuple." do tell!

Comment: I just added the Tuple solution. But it still involves a runtime function.

Comment: Is it possible to have a little more insight about what you're trying to do with that? Some other solutions might exist depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: No - it's more me satisfying my own curiousity around what's possible with the type system

Comment: I added a solution with enum, with limitations though.